# Select count from multiple tables

Tags: sql, join, count, union

I have a table containing a list of patterns that I use elsewhere.

Patterns:

- Top
- Bottom
- Middle

I also have multiple other tables that act as holding areas for data which each contain a pattern field. For each row in these tables in the pattern column there is one of the patterns from the patterns table.

What I need to do is, select the list of patterns from the patterns table in one column followed by a count of each pattern type for each table in the subsequent columns.

```text
PATTERNS    TABLE 1    TABLE2    TABLE3
Top         2          6         1
Bottom      1          3         7
Middle      5          7         2
```

Not sure if the way I explained it is clear, but in the example above there are 2 tops in table1, 6 tops in table2, etc. These are counts.

Comment: are the number of patterns dynamic? (meaning you may want 10 rows if 10 patterns exist?) and are there ONLY 4 tables (patterns, t1, t2,t3?) and lastly... what's the field name in each table holding pattern?

Comment: Patterns are static, and there are a total of 6 tables including patterns.

Comment: Field name is pattern_type, sorry didn't see the last part